# GCC Linker unexpectedly moves location counter backwards

Tags: linker, linker-errors, ld

I am developing new RTEMS BSP and I am modifying linker scripts

I modified [this linker script file](https://git.rtems.org/rtems/tree/bsps/arm/shared/start/linkcmds.base)

```
    .rwbarrier : ALIGN_WITH_INPUT {
        . = ALIGN (bsp_section_rwbarrier_align);
    } > REGION_DATA AT > REGION_DATA

    .vector : ALIGN_WITH_INPUT {
        bsp_section_vector_begin = .;
        . = . + DEFINED (bsp_vector_table_in_start_section) ? 0 : bsp_vector_table_size;
        bsp_section_vector_end = .;
    } > REGION_VECTOR AT > REGION_VECTOR
```

Lets suppose that we need to put .vector section in the middle of some memory region thus we need symbol `bsp_section_vector_begin` to be aligned to 128, so I added this one line:

```
    .vector : ALIGN_WITH_INPUT {
        . = ALIGN(128);
        bsp_section_vector_begin = .;
```

Now I get this error:

```
[build] linkcmds.base:xxx cannot move location counter backwards (from 0000000060022380 to 0000000060022370)
```

Which is pointing directly to this line

```
. = . + DEFINED (bsp_vector_table_in_start_section) ? 0 : bsp_vector_table_size;
```

But when changed this line to:

```
. = . + bsp_vector_table_size;
```

There is no error, linker is satisfied and system exceptions are working.

My question is: how can such an expression like this:

```
. = . + DEFINED (bsp_vector_table_in_start_section) ? 0 : bsp_vector_table_size;
```

evaluate in a such way it try to move location counter backward? I am sure `bsp_vector_table_size` is positive number, and my experiment confirmed it. `. = . + 0` works as well. What is wrong with this espression?